# Story with a blind hero who “hitch-hikes” into other people’s minds to see

Tags: story-identification

I read a book as a teenager in the '70s, which had a short one-word title as I remember it, in which the hero is rendered blind at some point, but achieves his mission by 'hitch-hiking' into other heads and using their eyes, shifting from one to another as he nears his goal. This is all very vague, but it was a long time ago! Any clues as to what I'm talking about?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be *Night Walk* by Bob Shaw (1967).

From the Wikipedia article, emphasis mine:

> He is blinded when Cherkassky shoots him in the face with a dart gun, destroying his
>   eyes. He is taken to a secret prison complex in the southernmost tip
>   of the most distant continent to convalesce. While he is there, he
>   enlists the aid of the scientific elite among the other political
>   prisoners there, and together they design a pair of electronic "sonar"
>   eyes. The headgear delivers different tones to distinguish various
>   objects. Later, they make another breakthrough: they make a device
>   that can sense and interpret **the nerve signals of the eyes of nearby
>   living things. Tallon can now see, but only through others' eyes**.
>   After they develop and test this device, Tallon and his partner
>   Winfield try to break out, but Winfield is shot during the attempt.
>   Tallon must flee alone, depending on encountering local animal life in
>   order to see.